# How to remove noise from wav file?

Tags: java, android, audio, wav

I am actually mixing two wav files using the simple equation (a+b)/2 where a and b are the samples from the two wav files.This is fine and I am able to listen the audio from both files at the same time.
But the problem is there is a lot of hssss noise (similar like the radio) playing in the background,how can I get rid of this white noise/noise.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a low pass filter to remove the noise.

[How to implement low pass filter using java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4026648/how-to-implement-low-pass-filter-using-java)

Please look into this link too
http://www.dsprelated.com/showcode/256.php