# How to get smooth orientation data in android

Tags: android, android-sensors, lowpass-filter

I have an app which uses orientation data which works very well using the pre API-8 method of using a `Sensor.TYPE_ORIENTAITON`. Smoothing that data was relatively easy.

I am trying to update the code to avoid using this deprecated approach. The new standard approach is to replace the single `Sensor.TYPE_ORIENTATION` with a `Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER` and `Sensor.TYPE_MAGENTIC_FIELD` combination. As that data is received, it is sent (via `SensorManager.getRotationMatrix()`) to `SensorManager.getOrientation()`. This (theoretically) returns the same information as `Sensor.TYPE_ORIENTATION` did (apart from different units and axis orientation).

However, this approach seems to generate data which is much more jittery (ie noisy) than the deprecated method (which still works). So, if you compare the same information on the same device, the deprecated method provides much less noisy data than the current method.

How do I get the actual same (less noisy) data that the deprecated method used to provide?

To make my question a little clearer: I have read various answers on this subject, and I have tried all sorts of filter: simple KF / IIR low pass as you suggest; median filter between 5 and 19 points, but so far I have yet to get anywhere close to the smoothness of the data the phone supplies via TYPE_ORIENTATION.

Comment: You need low pass filter as well as average out a history. If you compare TYPE_ORIENTATION and my answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17979238/android-getorientation-azimuth-gets-polluted-when-phone-is-tilted/17981374#17981374 you will see they are pretty much the equal.

Comment: It's funny. 7 years later, and I feel like this was a janky sensor

Comment: @MeetTitan Not sure I understand your comment - the same sensor here was delivering different (smoother) data via the (deprecated) method compared to the newer method, so it doesn't seem likely that the issue was the sensor.

Answer (score 10):

Apply a low-pass filter to your sensor output.

This is my low-pass filter method:

```
private static final float ALPHA = 0.5f;
//lower alpha should equal smoother movement
...
private float[] applyLowPassFilter(float[] input, float[] output) {
    if ( output == null ) return input;

    for ( int i=0; i<input.length; i++ ) {
        output[i] = output[i] + ALPHA * (input[i] - output[i]);
    }
    return output;
}
```

Apply it like so:

```
float[] mGravity;
float[] mGeomagnetic;
@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER)
        mGravity = applyLowPassFilter(event.values.clone(), mGravity);
    if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD)
        mGeomagnetic = applyLowPassFilter(event.values.clone(), mGeomagnetic);
    if (mGravity != null && mGeomagnetic != null) {
        float R[] = new float[9];
        float I[] = new float[9];

        boolean success = SensorManager.getRotationMatrix(R, I, mGravity, mGeomagnetic);
        if (success) {
            float orientation[] = new float[3];
            SensorManager.getOrientation(R, orientation);
            azimuth = -orientation[0];
            invalidate();
        }
    }
}
```

This is obviously code for a compass, remove what you don't need.

Also, take a look at this SE question [How to implement low pass filter using java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4026648/how-to-implement-low-pass-filter-using-java)

Comment: Sorry, I should have made my question a little clearer. I have read the other various answers on this subject, and I have tried all sorts of filter: simple KF / IIR low pass as you suggest; median filter between 5 and 19 points, but so far I have yet to get anywhere close to the smoothness of the data the phone supplies via TYPE_ORIENTATION.

Comment: @NeilTownsend, have you tried messing with the `ALPHA` variable in my lowpass-filter method? You may just be looking for a different `ALPHA` (for instance, try 0.15f next), equaling a more choppy, or smooth line drawn. If this was not the information you were looking for, my sincerest apologies.

Comment: Yes, I've tried from 0.1 to 0.9. It is either too laggy or too jittery, it doesn't get near the data from TYPE_ORIENTATION.

Comment: @NeilTownsend, hmmmm, my `applyLowPassFilter()` smooths my compass data out pretty nicely on my devices. Have you looked into device celebration, and seeing what accuracy you have with `onAccuracyChanged()`?

Comment: I have to confess that I haven't looked into device calibration yet - that may have to be the next step! I would expect the simple IIR filter you suggest to work, but somehow it doesn't seem to! Oh, well, I'll try some mean filters next :-)

Comment: @NeilTownsend, oh boy I didn't even see I said device celebration, curse my phone and its sensitive autocorrect. Calibrate your device and let me know what you're getting. If that fails, let me know what works for you, because I'm very curious now.

Comment: I quite like the idea of device celebration :-) I'll add to this question / answer once I get a solution I think is both smooth and responsive ...

Comment: I've spent some time hunting through the android source code, and a I've put up a fresh approach as an answer, which seems to need much less smoothing to be usable (and is hence more responsive).

Comment: @NeilTownsend Were you able to find a solution for this? I'm also stuck at this problem where either the compass values are too jittery or too laggy.

Comment: @droidster Afraid that I haven't got any further. It became apparent that it was going to take quite some effort to solve this one - even though it has been solved, no one seems to know how. Pick the bad solution that works best for your app!

Comment: @NeilTownsend In your low pass filter implementation, was the initial value of `output[0]` supposed to be the first value read from `input[0]`, to start with? I guess in your case the `output[0]` was also being computed inside the loop , so that when the first time this method was called, `output[0] = 0+ 0.5*(.....)"

Comment: @JohnLXiang I think your question was actually for MeetTitan as this answerr is his/hers.

Comment: @MeetTitan  In your low pass filter implementation, was the initial value of output[0] supposed to be the first value read from input[0], to start with? I guess in your case the output[0] was also being computed inside the loop , so that when the first time this method was called, `output[0] = 0+ 0.5*(.....)"

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that there is another, not particularly documented, way to get orientation data. Hidden in the list of sensor types is `TYPE_ROTATION_VECTOR`. So, set one up:

```
Sensor mRotationVectorSensor = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ROTATION_VECTOR);
sensorManager.registerListener(this, mRotationVectorSensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_GAME);
```

Then:

```
@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    final int eventType = event.sensor.getType();

    if (eventType != Sensor.TYPE_ROTATION_VECTOR) return;

    long timeNow            = System.nanoTime();

    float mOrientationData[] = new float[3];
    calcOrientation(mOrientationData, event.values.clone());

    // Do what you want with mOrientationData
}
```

The key mechanism is going from the incoming rotation data to an orientation vector via a rotation matrix. The slightly frustrating thing is the orientation vector comes from quaternion data in the first place, but I can't see how to get the quaternion delivered direct. (If you ever wondered how quaternions relate to orientatin and rotation information, and why they are used, see [here](http://developerblog.myo.com/quaternions/).)

```
private void calcOrientation(float[] orientation, float[] incomingValues) {
    // Get the quaternion
    float[] quatF = new float[4];
    SensorManager.getQuaternionFromVector(quatF, incomingValues);

    // Get the rotation matrix
    //
    // This is a variant on the code presented in
    // http://www.euclideanspace.com/maths/geometry/rotations/conversions/quaternionToMatrix/
    // which has been altered for scaling and (I think) a different axis arrangement. It
    // tells you the rotation required to get from the between the phone's axis
    // system and the earth's.
    //
    // Phone axis system:
    // https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_overview.html#sensors-coords
    //
    // Earth axis system:
    // https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorManager.html#getRotationMatrix(float[], float[], float[], float[])
    //
    // Background information:
    // https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix
    //
    float[][] rotMatF = new float[3][3];
    rotMatF[0][0] = quatF[1]*quatF[1] + quatF[0]*quatF[0] - 0.5f;
    rotMatF[0][1] = quatF[1]*quatF[2] - quatF[3]*quatF[0];
    rotMatF[0][2] = quatF[1]*quatF[3] + quatF[2]*quatF[0];
    rotMatF[1][0] = quatF[1]*quatF[2] + quatF[3]*quatF[0];
    rotMatF[1][1] = quatF[2]*quatF[2] + quatF[0]*quatF[0] - 0.5f;
    rotMatF[1][2] = quatF[2]*quatF[3] - quatF[1]*quatF[0];
    rotMatF[2][0] = quatF[1]*quatF[3] - quatF[2]*quatF[0];
    rotMatF[2][1] = quatF[2]*quatF[3] + quatF[1]*quatF[0];
    rotMatF[2][2] = quatF[3]*quatF[3] + quatF[0]*quatF[0] - 0.5f;

    // Get the orientation of the phone from the rotation matrix
    //
    // There is some discussion of this at
    // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30279065/how-to-get-the-euler-angles-from-the-rotation-vector-sensor-type-rotation-vecto
    // in particular equation 451.
    //
    final float rad2deg = (float)(180.0 / PI);
    orientation[0] = (float)Math.atan2(-rotMatF[1][0], rotMatF[0][0]) * rad2deg;
    orientation[1] = (float)Math.atan2(-rotMatF[2][1], rotMatF[2][2]) * rad2deg;
    orientation[2] = (float)Math.asin ( rotMatF[2][0])                * rad2deg;
    if (orientation[0] < 0) orientation[0] += 360;
}
```

This seems to give data very similar in feel (I haven't run numeric tests) to the old `TYPE_ORIENTATION` data: it was usable for motion control of the device with marginal filtering.

There is also helpful information [here](http://www.kircherelectronics.com/blog/index.php/11-android/sensors/15-android-gyroscope-basics), and a possible alternative solution [here](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/729759/Android-Sensor-Fusion-Tutorial).

Comment: I have looked into this method as well. Be weary using it as it uses gyroscope data instead of accelerometer data (they're different!). Gyroscopes are not in as many devices, to the best of my knowledge.

Comment: That's interesting, because about half the answers given to this problem rely on `TYPE_GRAVITY` which, according this http://davidcrowley.me/?tag=type_rotation_vector (about 16 minutes in) are also dependent on gyroscope data, and no one seems to mention that there's that limitation. I'll keep hunting!

Comment: Well as far as I know the accelerometer is in every device whereas the gyroscope is OEM dependent. Might not be bad if you have a gyroscope but you'd run into a problem if someone didn't.

Comment: @NeilTownsend May i know what do the multiplications of quatF mean? Also, why did you do a `Math.atan2` and `Math.asin`? It would help if u could explain the formulae

Comment: @user859385 It's a while since I've looked at this, but I've updated the answer with some (I hope) helpful links.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what worked out for me using `SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_GAME` for a fast update i.e.

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    sensor_manager.registerListener(this, sensor_manager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER), SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_GAME);
    sensor_manager.registerListener(this, sensor_manager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD), SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_GAME);
}
```

---

### MOVING AVERAGE

(less efficient)

```
private float[] gravity;
private float[] geomagnetic;
private float azimuth;
private float pitch;
private float roll; 

@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER)
        gravity = moving_average_gravity(event.values);
    if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD)
        geomagnetic = moving_average_geomagnetic(event.values);

    if (gravity != null && geomagnetic != null) {
        float R[] = new float[9];
        float I[] = new float[9];

        boolean success = SensorManager.getRotationMatrix(R, I, gravity, geomagnetic);
        if (success) {
            float orientation[] = new float[3];
            SensorManager.getOrientation(R, orientation);
            azimuth = (float) Math.toDegrees(orientation[0]);
            pitch = (float) Math.toDegrees(orientation[1]);
            roll = (float) Math.toDegrees(orientation[2]);
            //if(roll>-46F && roll<46F)view.setTranslationX((roll/45F)*max_translation); //tilt from -45° to 45° to x-translate a view positioned centrally in a layout, from 0 - max_translation
            Log.i("TAG","azimuth: "+azimuth+" | pitch: "+pitch+" | roll: "+roll);
        }
    }
}




private ArrayList<Float[]> moving_gravity;
private ArrayList<Float[]> moving_geomagnetic;
private static final float moving_average_size=12;//change

private float[] moving_average_gravity(float[] gravity) {
    if(moving_gravity ==null){
        moving_gravity =new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < moving_average_size; i++) {
            moving_gravity.add(new Float[]{0F,0F,0F});
        }return new float[]{0F,0F,0F};
    }

    moving_gravity.remove(0);
    moving_gravity.add(new Float[]{gravity[0],gravity[1],gravity[2]});
    return moving_average(moving_gravity);
}

private float[] moving_average_geomagnetic(float[] geomagnetic) {
    if(moving_geomagnetic ==null){
        this.moving_geomagnetic =new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < moving_average_size; i++) {
            moving_geomagnetic.add(new Float[]{0F,0F,0F});
        }return new float[]{0F,0F,0F};
    }

    moving_geomagnetic.remove(0);
    moving_geomagnetic.add(new Float[]{geomagnetic[0],geomagnetic[1],geomagnetic[2]});
    return moving_average(moving_geomagnetic);
}

private float[] moving_average(ArrayList<Float[]> moving_values){
    float[] moving_average =new float[]{0F,0F,0F};
    for (int i = 0; i < moving_average_size; i++) {
        moving_average[0]+= moving_values.get(i)[0];
        moving_average[1]+= moving_values.get(i)[1];
        moving_average[2]+= moving_values.get(i)[2];
    }
    moving_average[0]= moving_average[0]/moving_average_size;
    moving_average[1]= moving_average[1]/moving_average_size;
    moving_average[2]= moving_average[2]/moving_average_size;
    return moving_average;
}
```

---

### LOW PASS FILTER

(more efficient)

```
private float[] gravity;
private float[] geomagnetic;
private float azimuth;
private float pitch;
private float roll; 

@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER)
        gravity = LPF(event.values.clone(), gravity);
    if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD)
        geomagnetic = LPF(event.values.clone(), geomagnetic);

    if (gravity != null && geomagnetic != null) {
        float R[] = new float[9];
        float I[] = new float[9];

        boolean success = SensorManager.getRotationMatrix(R, I, gravity, geomagnetic);
        if (success) {
            float orientation[] = new float[3];
            SensorManager.getOrientation(R, orientation);
            azimuth = (float) Math.toDegrees(orientation[0]);
            pitch = (float) Math.toDegrees(orientation[1]);
            roll = (float) Math.toDegrees(orientation[2]);
            //if(roll>-46F && roll<46F)view.setTranslationX((roll/45F)*max_translation); //tilt from -45° to 45° to x-translate a view positioned centrally in a layout, from 0 - max_translation
            Log.i("TAG","azimuth: "+azimuth+" | pitch: "+pitch+" | roll: "+roll);
        }
    }
}




private static final float ALPHA = 1/16F;//adjust sensitivity
private float[] LPF(float[] input, float[] output) {
    if ( output == null ) return input;
    for ( int i=0; i<input.length; i++ ) {
        output[i] = output[i] + ALPHA * (input[i] - output[i]);
    }return output;
}
```

> **N.B** 
> moving average of 12 values instead as per [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4611772/10138416) 
> low pass filter of `ALPHA` = 0.0625 instead as per [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27847338/10138416)

Comment: thank you for the answer, it makes sense. Awkwardly, I am no longer coding for android, and not able to test your solution, so I can’t give it a “tick” but I would recommend others interested in this try your approach and feedback here!