# How to filter noise of gyroscope using javascript

Tags: javascript, filter, gyroscope

**I'm trying to build an app that will show values of gyroscope using javascript. The code I am using is attached below. The problem with my code is the output is changing so rapidly. Is there any filter available in javascript to filter the noise and make these values smooth and not to change so quickly.**

```
import React from 'react';
import { Gyroscope } from 'expo-sensors';
import { StyleSheet, Text, TouchableOpacity, View } from 'react-native';

export default class GyroscopeSensor extends React.Component {
  state = {
    gyroscopeData: {},
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.available();
    this._toggle();
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this._unsubscribe();
  }

  _toggle = () => {
    if (this._subscription) {
      this._unsubscribe();
    } else {
      this._subscribe();
    }
  };

  _slow = () => {
    Gyroscope.setUpdateInterval(2000);
  };

  _fast = () => {
    Gyroscope.setUpdateInterval(16);
  };

  _subscribe = () => {
    this._subscription = Gyroscope.addListener(result => {
      this.setState({ gyroscopeData: result });
    });
  };

  _unsubscribe = () => {
    this._subscription && this._subscription.remove();
    this._subscription = null;
  };
 available=async()=>{
    check=await Gyroscope.isAvailableAsync()
    console.log(check)
 }
  render() {
    let { x, y, z } = this.state.gyroscopeData;

    return (
      <View style={styles.sensor}>
        <Text>Gyroscope:</Text>
        <Text>
          x: {round(x)} y: {round(y)} z: {round(z)}
        </Text>

        <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={this._toggle} style={styles.button}>
            <Text>Toggle</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={this._slow} style={[styles.button, styles.middleButton]}>
            <Text>Slow</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={this._fast} style={styles.button}>
            <Text>Fast</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

function round(n) {
  if (!n) {
    return 0;
  }

  return Math.floor(n * 100) / 100;
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  buttonContainer: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    alignItems: 'stretch',
    marginTop: 15,
  },
  button: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#eee',
    padding: 10,
  },
  middleButton: {
    borderLeftWidth: 1,
    borderRightWidth: 1,
    borderColor: '#ccc',
  },
  sensor: {
    marginTop: 30,
    paddingHorizontal: 10,
  },
});
```

[image: The values of x,y,z is changing so rapidly]

Comment: One simple naive way to do it is to average the last couple hundred milliseconds of data or so.  This will remove any high frequency changes, leaving you with the major movements.

Comment: Just implement a low pass filter: https://www.dsprelated.com/freebooks/filters/Simplest_Lowpass_Filter_I.html or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4026648/how-to-implement-low-pass-filter-using-java

Comment: @Brad can you explain your answer more